# Getting selected value in Material-UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Here's the link for the sandbox code:** [Problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-mestorf-0lvt2?file=/src/App.js)

**Here's my problem:**
I can't retrieve the values in my autocomplete component just like my other components. If you click the Retrieve data button, it will retrieve the value for creator, title, description, project, severity, and status but the members field is empty. I think the problem is at my Autocomplete component (line 95), am I doing it right?

**Note: I remade the code so that I can share it on codesandbox, in my original code I'm using redux (but I'm pretty sure that the problem is not there but in the Autocomplete component)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use object instead of string in retrievedBugData: **{name: "Minnie Mouse"}**

---

```
const retrievedBugData = {
  creator: "Mickey Mouse",
  title: "A title",
  description: "A Description",
  project: "Project",
  members: [{name: "Minnie Mouse"}, {name: "Donald Duck"}],
  severity: "High",
  status: "Pending"
};
```

---

2. Set value of autocomplete to: **value={bugData.members}**

---

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    style={{ margin: "10px" }}
    limitTags={1}
    value={bugData.members}
    options={sampleUsers}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    fullWidth
    )}
/>
```

---

3. Use object inside **on change** event
   https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-pare-4w60h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you @Akif! I finally know where it all went wrong. It's on retrievedBugData, my members array is just an array of strings in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
     <Autocomplete
        multiple
        style={{ margin: "10px" }}
        limitTags={1}
        options={sampleUsers}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        fullWidth
        onChange={(e, newMember) =>
          setBugData({ ...bugData, members: newMember })      //return new member
        }
```

it works [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-tree-yotmj)

Comment: Hi @Yoel, I tried that in my original code but it didn't work. Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching the docs on how to grab the value. It just needed a second parameter. e.target.value wasn't working.